# How to ORDER BY on this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

My current query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `reported_users`
GROUP BY `reported_user`
ORDER BY ???
```

I have a `reported_users` table. When users on my site report another user for breaking the rules the reported user is inserted as a row in this table. So the same user can have multiple rows in the table. To make sure I get each user only once I am using `GROUP BY` on the `reported_user` field. But how can I `ORDER BY` users who were reported the most to least. So if the table looks like this:

```
reported_user | reporter
---------------------------
Joe           | Bob
Jake          | Nady
Lisa          | Tim
Joe           | Jim
Joe           | Foo
Lisa          | Bar
```

the query should return:

```
Joe (3)
Lisa (2)
Jake (1)
```

I would also like to return how many times each user was reported. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT reported_user, count(*)
FROM reported_users
GROUP BY reported_user
ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT reported_user, count(*)
FROM reported_users
GROUP BY reported_user
ORDER BY count(*) Desc
```